# NSCompoundPredicate error in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nscompoundpredicate, xcode6.1

Back in Xcode 6, in a project using Core Data I had the following line. It worked fine.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [predicate, datePredicate])
```

*predicate* and *datePredicate* are of `NSPredicate` type.

Yesterday I updated to Xcode 6.1 and now this above line gives this error **Could not find member 'AndPredicateType'**. Specifying the entire value like this `NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType` didn't work either.

Then I changed the line to use its convenience method line below.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates([predicate, datePredicate])
```

Now I get a new error **Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'NSPredicate?'**. I don't understand why. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/index.html) doesn't show any deprecations or changes to `NSCompoundPredicate` either.

Can anyone please tell me how to correct this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initializer

```
extension NSPredicate {
    convenience init?(format predicateFormat: String, _ args: CVarArgType...)
}
```

is a *failable initializer* now. It returns an optional `NSPredicate?` and you have
to unwrap the result (or use optional binding). For example:

```
let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [predicate!, datePredicate!])
// Or:
let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates([predicate!, datePredicate!])
```

References:

- Swift blog: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17
- Swift documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html

Comment: Just found it myself too. haha. Thank you. Good to know the actual reason behind it.